# Python OCR Sudoku image

Tags: python, ocr

I have searched and found the following python code but it doesn't return the result as expected. I need to use ocr to convert the numbers on the sudoku image and read it as a grid

```
import cv2
from imutils import contours
import numpy as np

# Load image, grayscale, and adaptive threshold
image = cv2.imread('Sample.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,57,5)

# Filter out all numbers and noise to isolate only boxes
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 1000:
        cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, (0,0,0), -1)

# Fix horizontal and vertical lines
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,5))
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, vertical_kernel, iterations=9)
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,1))
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, horizontal_kernel, iterations=4)

# Sort by top to bottom and each row by left to right
invert = 255 - thresh
cnts = cv2.findContours(invert, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
(cnts, _) = contours.sort_contours(cnts, method="top-to-bottom")

sudoku_rows = []
row = []
for (i, c) in enumerate(cnts, 1):
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 50000:
        row.append(c)
        if i % 9 == 0:  
            (cnts, _) = contours.sort_contours(row, method="left-to-right")
            sudoku_rows.append(cnts)
            row = []

# Iterate through each box
for row in sudoku_rows:
    for c in row:
        mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)
        result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, mask)
        result[mask==0] = 255
        cv2.imshow('result', result)
        cv2.waitKey(175)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('invert', invert)
cv2.waitKey()
```

I have no great idea how to solve such a problem and forgive me if I was a beginner.
Here's sample of the image.
[image]

Comment: "it doesn't return the result as expected" => What does it return ?

Comment: it returns a grid with black pixels inside the squares. I need an array of numbers [6,8,3,0,0,0,0,5,0], something like that or a grid with the numbers extracted

Answer (score 1):

The best I could do CLI wise was run the image via any converter into PNM format which is preferred for most OCR apps, however most OCR apps will convert to Plain Text and those 7 may sometimes be seen as T (easy enough in this simplified case to Find and Replace).

The BIGGER hurdle is OCR just like PDF has no concept of Indents or margins so now we get this output. And no amount of correction of char spacing would help.

[image]

Thus your solution may rely on convert Image to vector placement by convert to PDF XY positions then with PDF OCR attempt to get the Character Layout from the pdf extraction result.

Python libs have data frame solutions that attempt to maintain tabular positions, however I don't do python to suggest which one can do this well.